# sfdx Error while creating package version

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm working on "Unlocked Packages for Customers" trailhead module. While creating the package version I'm getting below error:
**ERROR:  The --path (-d) value, [force-app], and --package (-p) value, [th-dreamhouse], were both found in sfdx-project.json but don’t match. If you supply both values, they must match the path and package values in one of the packageDirectories.**

My sfdx command: 
*sfdx force:package:version:create -p th-dreamhouse -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub*

My sfdx-project.json file:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "dreamhouse",
            "versionName": "ver 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
        },
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "th-dreamhouse",
            "versionName": "ver 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "44.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "dreamhouse": "0Ho0I000000PAscSAG",
        "dreamhouse@1.0.0-1": "04t0I000001E1xdQAC",
        "th-dreamhouse": "0Ho0I000000PAshSAG"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error is occurring because you have two different packages using the `force-app` path. Since you're specifying both `-d` and `-p` in your command the path you provide for the `-d` flag has to match up with path for the package you provide with the `-p` flag. But your path is used for both `dreamhouse` and `th-dreamhouse`, so your path doesn't actually match up with the package provided.

Is there a reason you have `force-app` used for both packages? It seems like that's an error and if you either remove the `dreamhouse` package from your json file (if it's unnecessary) or set a different path for it then you should stop receiving that error.

Comment: Just an addition to this, for any other package with same path, modify that path to nested path like force-app/main/default and then try again. The path for other package that you changed just now, need to be a valid path

Answer (score 2):

Other solution that I test here:
Duplicate directory force-app with other name how force-app-2

Try this command change directory.
sfdx force:package:version:create -p th-dreamhouse -d force-app2 -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub

Works for me, tks

Answer (score 0):

I removed this part from the **sfdx-project.json** file

```
{
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "dreamhouse",
            "versionName": "ver 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
        },
```

And it worked .

**One path cannot be used by more than one package **

And be sure to change the default attribute  to true !!

```
{
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "th-dreamhouse",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "default": true
        }
```